# jQuery with elements generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working with jQuery for a pair of weeks and I've noticed it works fine with objects that are in the original HTML document, but when I generate a new element using jQuery the library doesn't get any of its events.

Let's say I try to run something like this:

```
$('.whatever').click(function() {
  alert("ALERT!");
});
```

If the HTML does have something like this:

```
<span class="whatever">Whatever</span>
```

Then clicking on the word `Whatever` gets me a nice alert.

But if the `span` element is added dynamically using jQuery, nothing happens when clicking on it.

Is there a way to make jQuery work with those elements, somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thats because the :
<sub>(corrected)</sub>

```
$('.whatever').click(function() {
  alert("ALERT!");
});
```

Means, in literal terms:

```
Find all elements currently on the page that have the class ".whatever"
Foreach element in that result set, bind this function to its click event
```

so naturally, adding a new DOM element wont automagically apply the click.

the best way to solve this is create bindings during your insert phase, ie:

```
  var x = document.createElement("span"); 
  $(x).click(function(){ });  //etc 
  $(somcontiner).append(x);
```

#### Warning on simply rebinding everything

If done wrong, it can lead to undesired effects, ie, making the number of times the event triggers something increase. To stop this, you may need to first unbind them to delete the previous passes binds.

ie,

```
$(x).click(foo); 
$(x).click(bar);  //foo and bar should both execute.
```

so to stop this, you need

```
$(x).unbind("click");
$(x).click(foo);
```

in the rebind.

Answer (score 6):

If you have jQuery 1.3 or later, try using [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) for adding events to dynamically generated elements:

```
$('.whatever').live("click", function() {
  alert("ALERT!");
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly, wow I wasn't aware of the .live() method.  That is very very handy.  Thanks Alex.

Comment: @Alex, you should have proposed him to use `$.delegate` instead of `$.live`. If indeed, it was possible for him to do so.

Comment: @Cybrex, I dont think delegate was avaiable that time, it came after live

Comment: @refhat That's correct, [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) was introduced in 1.4.2.

Comment: The new way to do this in jQuery 1.7+ is to use `.on()`.

Comment: What if you don't want to bind an event, but just want to select an element in the dynamically generated HTML?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everybody.

Somehow I thought elements were added to the DOM automatically by jQuery just by adding them anywhere.

I've also found some extra information on the topic:

http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request.3F

http://learningjquery.com/2008/03/working-with-events-part-1

http://learningjquery.com/2008/05/working-with-events-part-2

Just in case somebody else needs it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebind it.

```
function bindme(){
    $('.whatever').click(function(){
        alert('binded');
    });
};

bindme();

//function that will generate something

function foo(){
   $('.whatever').val('oryt');
   bindme();//rebind itagain
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also look at [reglib](http://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/reglib_javascript_library_now_available), a similar library that allows for the style of programming you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Also, there's an excellent plugin for jQuery which takes care of this, called [livequery](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbrandonaaron.net%2Fdocs%2Flivequery%2F&ei=CTshSaKvD4-M0QSDoK20CA&usg=AFQjCNHiEmyrBNe5Tyz1BDqcamx3ouO9ww&sig2=vzsusErgyoB2iPlq4JIjpg)